# Trying to gather only the value of a JSON key/value pair

Tags: json, ansible

I am using the community Ansible XML module to parse a devices configuration. I have the output I need, but its outputting it in JSON key/value format when I need the value only.

Sample output:

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "actions": {
        "namespaces": {},
        "state": "present",
        "xpath": "/response/result/system/app-version"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "count": 1,
    "matches": [
        {
            "app-version": "8779-8405"
        }
    ],
    "msg": 1
}
```

Where I dont want to see:

```
"app-version": "8779-8405"
```

But only "8779-8405". However I cant find any simple way to split the values short of a regex replacement, which I am trying to avoid. I am sure there is a simple way to split the values, but its escaping all the searches I am doing.

Comment: Could do a non-regex replacement of `"app-version":` with a blank string?

Comment: Yeah, I find it super odd that I have to 'deal' with this. Why isn't there an easy way to refer to the first or second part of the pair? Thats why I think I am missing something.

Comment: Also, you'll have to delete the `{` and `}` to make it a string array and therefore valid JSON, ie the final result should be`"matches": ["8779-8405"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***I cant find any simple way to split the values short of a regex replacement, which I am trying to avoid.***

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    result: {
      "actions": {
        "namespaces": {},
        "state": "present",
        "xpath": "/response/result/system/app-version"
        },
    "changed": false,
    "count": 1,
    "matches": [
        {
            "app-version": "8779-8405"
        }
    ],
    "msg": 1
    }

  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ (result.matches | first | from_yaml)['app-version'] }}"
```

will result into the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***
  msg: 8779-8405
```

Comment: Well there is my problem. It looked like JSON, so I assumed it was JSON. 

The "first" sorts it into a list correct? "from_yaml" converts YAML into a string, and then I just need to reference which pair I am querying from? So in theory if I had a huge list of values, I could output the much larger XML list directly, and do a:

"{{  (result.matches | first | from_yaml)['valueInXMLlist']  }}"

Am I understanding how that line works?

Comment: "_It looked like JSON, so I assumed it was JSON._", right, it is. "_The `first` sorts it into a list correct?_", actually no. The key `matches` contains a list with one element only. The `first` filter deliver the first element only, leaving one without a list. Then, there is a string with key:value. [`from_yaml` filter – Convert YAML string into variable structure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/from_yaml_filter.html) so one can catch up the value.

Comment: I don't quite understand yet, but I am going to find more examples of how to use from_yaml, and can confirm I did get the string I needed as output. Appreciate your help.